# How to create a function

Tags: windows, function, task, finalescript

Is there any way to define a function in finalescript?

Let's say I have a finalescript, and as part of it, I have a block of code that transposes some measures n lines. But, I feel that it would be much more convenient to create a function `transpose(n)` that transposes it by n half-steps.

So, is there any way to do this in finalescript?

Answer (score 3):

**No**. In the [closest thing I could find to a documentation](https://www.finalemusic.com/UserManuals/Finale2012Mac/Content/Finale/FinaleScript_plug_in.htm), there was nothing written about functions.

But, when I thought about your particular question, would you ever need a `transpose(n)` function? Because if you're going to have a transposition script, wouldn't you simply transpose everything?

An example from the [finalescript blog](http://www.finalemusic.com/blog/can-finalescript-do-this/):

```
//set this to the key of the instrument transposition

key signature F major

//highlight the staff that needs to be made key independent
//or you can set the staff to be selected by removing the
//comment slashes and changing the number

select staff 1

staff attributes
check “Key Signature” Near “Independent Elements”
press “ok”

//Set this to the key of the piece, such as C major

key signature C Major

//to correct the pitch of the staff you need to set this

menu item “Utilities/Transpose”
radio “Down”
radio “Chromatically”
popup “Perfect Fourth”
type “0” near “Octave(s)
uncheck “Preserve Original Notes”
press “OK”
```

I agree that it would be very nice and convenient to have functions in finalescript, but I guess that finalescript does not have them.

Good luck!